# Unable to access Redmi Note 5 Pro from Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb, mtp, redmi-device

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish), and I've Redmi Note 5 Pro on MIUI Global 10.0 ROM.
When I connect my device and try to access the drive, I get the following error :

> Unable to access "SDM636 MTP SN:E5BA4F65"
>
> Couldn't find matching udev device.

I asked the same question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085575/unable-to-connect-to-mtp-device) about 20 days ago, but didn't get any response.

Output of some useful commands :

**$ lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:b006 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 2717:ff48  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f2:b50d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**$ mtp-filetree**

```
Device 0 (VID=2717 and PID=ff48) is a Xiaomi Mi-2s (MTP).
Attempting to connect device(s)
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Device: (NULL)
LIBMTP_Get_Storage(): Resource temporarily unavailable
OK.
```

I also tried to install `android-udev-rules` and followed the steps as described [here](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules#ubuntu). But still no progress.

I noticed something unusual, when I try to install an App from Android Studio, *it worked* (Only the installation, I'm still not able to access anything else). I don't why, but the app is there in my phone but I'm unable to get the Logcat.

PS: I also asked the same question [here](https://en.miui.com/thread-4463792-1-1.html) as well.

Comment: If you're downvoting the question atleast have the courtesy to comment why you did so.

Comment: as a opinion did you enable file transfer mode at phone? maybe enabling developer options and enabling usb debugging may help

Comment: @AlpAltunel Yes, `usb debugging` is on. That's why I was able to install my app :P . Not only that I also tried to connect it as Transfer photos (PTP), but still nothing works.

Comment: try when  you are connected to the phone to computer and also enable verify apps via USB. if you turn it on and connect to computer it disables it. My huawei behaves like that. after connecting phone check usb debugging is on or off. Chinese phones do it like this.

Comment: I have this exact problem and exact same issue. I hope someone sheds some light.

Comment: @LuisAlejandro I'm able to partially access my device. I wanted to use it for Android Studio only, so I installed adb-rules and adb-devices via sudo apt-get install and it's working now. Though I'm not able to access the device from File Explorer. But I'm able to read the contents of the Storage and other locations, maybe make a copy of them too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install go-mtpfs with apt-get install, then execute the following:

```
go-mtpfs [FOLDER]
```

And your device should be mounted :)

Comment: What should be in the [FOLDER]?

Comment: The folder where you want to mount the contents of the phone. Something like /media/android will do. Rememeber setting correct permissions for the folder when you create it.